# What is the purpose of the uucico shell on HP-UX, Solaris, and possibly other Unix varieties?

Tags: shell, solaris, hp-ux

I'm not a Unix admin myself, but I work with Unix servers on a regular basis and am fairly familiar with their workings. So maybe this is something obvious, but it's not something I can find an answer for and my SAs all seem equally clueless. So I'm asking you guys.

On Every HP-UX and Solaris server I've worked with there has been this shell, /usr/lib/uucp/uucico which seems to come out of the box with weird file permissions and is only used by the uucp user, but it is listed in /etc/shells as a valid shell.

I've tried to find a good answer online, but as far as I can tell there doesn't seem to be a good reason for uucp to have its own special shell and could just as easily work with sh or something. So I think I must be missing something. What is the purpose of this shell? Why is it there, and what does it do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is explained in [*Practical Unix & Internet Security*](http://www.diablotin.com/librairie/networking/puis/ch15_03.htm) as a security feature:  uucp has to log in to issue commands, and `uucico` is a limited-functionality shell, with a separate login/password from regular accounts.

Comment: Thanks, that's an informative read. Interestingly, one of our guidelines that I check for is ownership of shells, with the requirement that root be the owner (or maybe bin too, I don't remember offhand). With the uucp user intentionally being the owner for security purposes, I think I might have to look at having those requirements revised.

Comment: @Matt I can't speak for HP-UX, but  if you have no need to use uucp on Solaris, you can remove the `nuucp` entry from `/etc/passwd`. Nothing will break.The `uucp` user and group are used not only for uucp but also for some related files such as tip, uuencode,  uudecode and /dev/cua*, so it should probably be kept, but it should not be login-able.

Comment: Not many people use `uucp` nowadays.  But OP may be constrained on the approaches used (package removal is preferable to tweaking permissions).

Comment: IMHO `uucico` is not a limited functionality shell. Its default use is to scan the `/var/spool/uucp` directories for files.  If such files exist, a connection to a remote system is initiated using the line protocol specified for the remote system and the files are transferred.

Answer (score 0):

It's not really a shell but a communications program that speaks the  uucp protocol for transferring files.  If uucp has been appropriately configured another machine can log in as uucp to initiate file transfers between them.

As an alternative to sharing the uucp account remote machines could have their own dedicated unix account with uucico as the "shell".  It is probably in /etc/shells to facilitate such a setup.

The funny permissions (suid and sgid) are so it can access serial ports and enable it to manipulate the uucp spool.